# How to put QR code into image control of Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I am studying the QR Code these few days. So, I am trying to do the QR code.
My purpose is to select the Employee table and selects out two-column(Id and Name),
When I load Employee Id, I want to let my Id become a QR code and put into Gridview image control

Below is my Front end program

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="QRcodeSample.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QR Code">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="ImgQRcode" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my backend code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    GetEmployeeNumber();
}

public void GetEmployeeNumber(){
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
     cn.ConnectionString = 
     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
     cn.Open();

     string sql = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName FROM Employees";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn);
     SqlDataReader drEmployee = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(drEmployee);

     //Load DataTable
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
           DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
           string number = dt.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();

           GenerateQRCode(number);
     }

     GridView1.DataSource = drEmployee;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}

private void GenerateQRCode(string number)
{
   var writer = new BarcodeWriter()
   {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions()
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            CharacterSet = "UTF-8"
        }
   }
};

var result = writer.Write(number);
string path = Server.MapPath("/images/" + number + ".jpg");
var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);

using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
         barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
         byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
         fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}

     //Here is my problem, what should I do?
     //ImgQRcode.Visible = true;
    //ImgQRcode.ImageUrl = "~/images/QRImage.jpg";
}
```

Comment: There is no problem here, only a desire and statement of intent. narrow this down with a specific domain, and issue. if the database code works we dont need to see it, if the file stream code works, we dont need that either

Comment: You can send the file to the image src as base64, or create a generic handler that serves images.